# I am unable to find "build configuration language" option when creating a new project in the android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to use kotlin dsl as build configuration language.
but when creating a new project in the android studio. It is not showing the option to choose.
like below image.
[needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBL2T.jpg)
like the above image there is a option to choose.
but in my android studio there is not any option like that.
[have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVujv.png)

can anyone help me?
Thank You :)

I search about it but unable to find the solution instead I found articles about migrate from groovy to kotlin. and I know to how to do that but very time consuming.

Comment: Android Studio is much more opinionated than IntelliJ. I'm not surprised it takes this choice away, as it does many others. I'd expect it uses Kotlin, which is the one you want anyway.

Comment: Okay, just tried with latest Android Studio and it doesn't in fact use Kotlin. So much for sensible defaults.

Comment: It is not using kotlin by default, I have to manually migrate from groovy to kotlin
I have to change build.gradle to build.gradle.kts manually

Comment: That's what I said :) I'm not sure what to say other than I'm disappointed in Android Studio (again)

Comment: Ok, so I found a answer. They are working on that from the new version of android studio **which is Giraffe** the option to choose "builld configuration language" will be available.
Thank you @Jorn you gave me your time.